# Flask cookies set in Postman but not in browser

Tags: javascript, python, flask, cookies

I've problem with Flask cookies, my routes is working in Postman but when I tried to test with my front-end, my cookie doesn't set.

This is my route to connect user :

```
@users.route('/api/user/login', methods=['POST'])
def check_password():
    req = request.get_json()
    email = req['email']
    password = req['password']
    query = Users().get_by_email(email)
    if query:
        if bcrypt.check_password_hash(query['password'], password):
            res = make_response("Vous êtes connecté")
            res.set_cookie('status', 'connected', max_age=60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 2, domain='127.0.0.1')
            session.modified = True
            return res
        else:
            return "Password incorect"
    else:
        return "Pas d'utilisateur"
```

This is my route to check the user status (to know if cookie is set or not) :

```
@users.route('/api/user/status', methods=['GET'])
def status():
    if request.cookies.get('status'):
        return "Connecté"
    else:
        return "Pas encore connecté"
```

And this is the AJAX request in my front to call my route :

```
    userStatus() {
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/api/user/status",
            })
            .done((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .fail(() => {
                console.log("PAS OK")
            })
    }
```

If someone can help me about this problem it will be very nice.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Did you enabled CORS ?
because when you are calling with javascript a api, you will need to enable CORS to make javascript calls to your server

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).